# Vimeo Player API "Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided () does not match the recipient window's origin ('')"

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

Tengo un CPT en wordpress que muestra un iframe de vimeo dentro de un fancybox, hasta ahi todo ok. He integrado la API player Vimeo, para desencadenar funciones en los eventos, al finalizar el video muestro otra capa diferente a la inicial en la que hay un botón de "volver a ver".

A partir de la segunda vez que llamo a la funcion que genera el objeto player me da el error

"Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://player.vimeo.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('http://dominio.com')"

Esta es la vista

```
  <div class="container-fluid videobg">

<div class="destacado-container video-plus-container" style="background-image: url( '<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/img/destacados-bg.png' );">


    <!-- imagen video  -->
    <div class="container" style="margin-top: 83px;">
        <div class="videobox" style="position: relative;">


            <a data-fancybox class="playVideo playContent playButton" href="#myvideo"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/img/play-off.png" alt=""></a><img src="<?php echo $img['url'] ?>" alt="" class="img-responsive">

        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- fin imagen video -->

    <!-- imagen final video -->
    <div class="container container-final" style="margin-top: 83px; display: none; ">
        <div class="videobox-final col-xs-12" style="background-image: url('<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/img/final.png'); background-size: 100% auto; padding: 0em 0em 1.5em 0em">

            <div class="col-xs-6">

                <h2 class="text-center title-left">Descubra un horizonte de oportunidades</h2>
                <div class="col-xs-12 text-center"><img class="logo_cyc img-responsive" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/img/logo_cyc.png" alt=""></div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 text-center masinfo-box" style="">
                    <a href="" class="masinfo">Más Información</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 volver_a_ver">
                    <a data-fancybox href="#myvideo" class="playVideo playAgain">
                        <span class="fa fa-undo"></span>
                        <span>Volver a ver</span>
                    </a>
                </div>



            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-6">

                <div class="col-xs-12 title-right">
                    <h3 style="">Te recomendamos: </h3>

                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 text-center sugest">

                    <a href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/img/sugerencia_1.png" alt="" class="img-responsive"></a>


                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 text-center sugest">
                    <a href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/img/sugerencia_2.png" alt="" class="img-responsive"></a>


                </div>


            </div>          


        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- fin imagen final video --> 
</div>
```

```
    <!-- etiqueta info -->
    <div class="label-container" style="position: absolute; top: 12px; right: 20px;border-radius: 5px;background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5); padding: .4em;display: none; z-index: 9999999999;">
        <a href="<?php the_field('url_destino_etiqueta') ?>" class="label_enlace col-xs-12" style="">
            <div style="" class="label">
                <span class="label-arrow" style="display:none;"><img src="http://laneurona.com/wp-content/themes/la_neurona/img/red-arrow.png" alt="" style="height: 30px;padding-bottom: .5em"></span>
                <span class="label-text" style="display:none;font-weight:100;font-size: 2em; margin-top: -.5em; cursor:pointer; padding: 10px"><?php the_field('texto_etiqueta') ?></span>
                <span class="fa fa-info-circle fa-3x info-icon" style=""></span>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <!-- fin etiqueta info -->

    <iframe id="vimeo_player" src="<?php the_field('video_plus') ?>" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>

</div>
<!-- fin contenido fancybox -->
```

Este es el js

```
(function($) {



    $(".playContent").click(function(){


        //VIMEO API PLAYER
        console.log('api loading');
            var iframe_options = {
            color: '#ffffff',
            origin: '*',

        };

        //vimeo api segun su doc
        var url_frame = $('iframe').attr('src');
        $('iframe').attr('src',url_frame +'?player_id=vimeo_player&loop=0&autopause=0');
        var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
        var player = new Vimeo.Player(iframe , iframe_options);







        //console.log(player);

        console.log('playing video');

        //forzamos play
        player.play().catch(function(error) {
            console.error('error playing the video:', error.name);
        });


        player.on('play',onPlay);

        player.on('pause',onPause);


        player.on('ended', onFinish);

        player.on('progress',onPlayProgress);

        player.on('seeked',isSeeked);


        player.getVideoTitle().then(function(title) {
            console.log('title:', title);
        });

        player.getVideoId().then(function(id) {
            // id = the video id
            console.log('id');
            console.log(id);

        }).catch(function(error) {
            // an error occurred
            console.log(error);

        });


            function onPlay(data) {
                console.log('play!!');
                console.log(data);

                //eliminamos el boton de cierre del iframe
                $('button.fancybox-close-small').attr('style','display : none');

                /* -  Aparece el icono de info 15s despues cargar el video  - */

                setTimeout(function(){
                    jQuery('.label-container').fadeIn();       
                }, 10000);

            /* -  Fin Aparece el icono de info 15s despues cargar el video  - */

                console.log('go to ajax');
                //ejemplo ajax wp
                $.ajax({

                   type: "POST",
                    url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php", 
                    data: {'action':'test_ajax','idevento':'321'},
                    success: function(dataResponse){

                        console.log(dataResponse);

                    },
                    error: function(dataResponse){
                        console.log('error!!');
                        console.log(msg.statusText);
                    }
                });


            }//fin onPlay

            function onPause(data) {
                console.log('paused');
                 console.log(data);
            }

            function onFinish(data) {

                 $.fancybox.close();
                 $('.video-plus-container .container').fadeOut();
                 $('.video-plus-container .container-final').fadeIn();

            }

            function onPlayProgress(data) {
                console.log(data.seconds + '\'s played');
            }

            function isSeeked(data){
                console.log('seeked');
                console.log(data);
            }


    });//fin onclick



    //altura 
    var height = screen.height/1.5;

    //70% del ancho de pantalla
    //var width = screen.width*.7;



    /*fancy box*/
    $(".playVideo").fancybox({



        beforeShow : function(){

                //asignamos tamaño
                this.width =  16/9 * height;
                this.height = height;


        }, 

        afterClose : function(){

             //acciones al cierre

        }       

    });
    /*fancy box*/
```

})( jQuery );

Se que el problema es que no coincide el origen con el destino y mas puesto que en mi dominio no hay certificado SSL. Lo que no entiendo es porque la primera vez no me da ningún problema.

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

Prueba cambiando la URL del fichero que tratas de embeber. Por ejemplo:

```
var id = getId(url);
  return '//www.youtube.com/embed/' + id + '?showinfo=0&enablejsapi=1&origin=http://localhost:9000';
}
```

Pasa a ser:

```
var id = getId(url);
  return 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + id + '?showinfo=0&enablejsapi=1&origin=http://localhost:9000';
}
```

[idea original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27573017/failed-to-execute-postmessage-on-domwindow-https-www-youtube-com-http) de Chris Franklin

Comment: Gracias. Pero no resuelve el problema. Ya probe esta solución hace tiempo